# Telegram timeout

Tags: telegram, aiogram

using aiogram 3 i try to download sond for 1hr+. download is good, but sending via telegram so week..

```
@router.message(Command(commands=['youtube']))
async def music_download(message: types.Message):
    try:
        text = message.text.replace('/youtube ', '')
        song_files = await download_song(text)
        print(song_files)
        if song_files:
            for song_file in song_files:
                pprint.pprint(song_file)
                file = FSInputFile(song_file)
                pprint.pprint(file)
                await message.reply_audio(audio=file)
                time.sleep(1)
```

and of course error: Failed to fetch updates - TelegramNetworkError: Telegram server says Request timeout error
Sleep for 1.000000 seconds and try again... (tryings = 0, bot id = 1855074508)
Telegram server says ClientOSError: [Errno 2] Can not write request body for `https://api.telegram.org/bot1855074508:AAEFuvZkVIgZy0SB18dXRe2JK2xBV66O2eQ/sendAudio`

I try to send song wherever of minutes or hours. But there`s error...

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.